# framework not found AWSCore for architecture arm64 in theos makefile

Tags: ios, makefile, theos

So I downloaded latest AWS iOS SDK source code, and change AWSS3 and AWSCore into static library format, and build it with latest Xcode 8 to get the frameworks;

Then I put it under my project folder AWS/

And adding below makefile code:

```
MyWorker_LDFLAGS += AWS/AWSCore.framework/AWSCore AWS/AWSS3.framework/libAWSS3
```

Then it reports:

```
ld: framework not found AWSCore for architecture arm64
```

I double checked the framework, it has arm64:

```
xuan:AWSCore.framework xuan$ lipo -detailed_info AWSCore 
Fat header in: AWSCore
fat_magic 0xcafebabe
nfat_arch 2
architecture armv7
    cputype CPU_TYPE_ARM
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_V7
    offset 48
    size 9208616
    align 2^2 (4)
architecture arm64
    cputype CPU_TYPE_ARM64
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM64_ALL
    offset 9208664
    size 9764784
    align 2^3 (8)
```

Then, I tried to move `AWSCore` into `AWS/lib/libAWSCore.a`, so does `AWSS3`, and change makefile like this:

```
MyWorker_LDFLAGS = -L./AWS/lib -lsqlite3 -lz -lAWSCore -lAWSS3
```

It still reports:

```
ld: framework not found AWSCore for architecture arm64
```

I tried to only build arm64 arch, but it does not help. Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you create a new folder called `frameworks` in your project root and put the AWS SDK there.

Then you can do:

`MyWorker_LDFLAGS = -F./frameworks
MyWorker_FRAMEWORKS = AWSCore AWSS3`

Comment: why should this address the problem? It's not about can't find framework, it's about no matching arch

Comment: I think you should try redownloading the SDK. It may be corrupt as I don't experience the same problem as you do.

This also works for me (when renaming AWSCore to libAWSCore.a):
`MyWorker_LDFLAGS = -L./AWSCore2.framework -lAWSCore`

Anyways, you should properly link to the framework and not directly to the library, much easier.